# Mongoose remove one object from array of array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have Mongoose schema like this:

```
{
......
project: [
  {
    Name: String,
    Criteria:[
      {
        criteriaName:String,
      }
    ]
  }
]
......
}
```

And I want to remove one of the objects of criteria array which is in the array of project based on the object id

I tried the code following

```
criteria.findOneAndUpdate({
    "_id": uid,
},{  $pull: { "project.Criteria": { _id: cid } }  }, (err) => {
......
}
```

However this cannot work, it said "Cannot use the part (Criteria) of (project.Criteria) to traverse the element"

Comment: It must be `{  $pull: { "project.$.Criteria": { _id: cid } }  }`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet It said `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.` I don't know if it can work in an array of array

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do it in one query to the database? If not, the following solution may work for you:

```
criteria.findOne({ _id: uid })
.then((obj) => {
  // Filter out the criteria you wanted to remove
  obj.project.Criteria = obj.project.Criteria.filter(c => c._id !== cid);

  // Save the updated object to the database
  return obj.save();
})
.then((updatedObj) => {
  // This is the updated object
})
.catch((err) => {
  // Handle error
});
```

Sorry if the .then/.catch is confusing. I can rewrite with callbacks if necessary, but I think this looks a lot cleaner. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I want to do it in one query the database to make it looks clean and efficient, but your code looks quite clean